How to extract angular component from a federated module using only SystemJS
I am trying to expose components from a angular microfrontend using webpack module federation, below is how I am doing with webpack
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");

module.exports = {
  output: {
  publicPath: "http://localhost:4201/",  // Ensure this matches your Angular app's URL
  uniqueName: "angularMFE",
  library: {
    type: "system",
  },
},
plugins: [
  new ModuleFederationPlugin({
    name: "angularMFE",
    filename: "remoteEntry.js",
    exposes: {
      './AppComponent': './src/app/app.component.ts',  // Path to your Angular component
    },
    shared: {
      "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true },
      "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true },
      "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true },
    }
  })],
};

I am able to access the remoteEntry.js file at http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.js
Here is what I did using systemJS
<script type="systemjs-importmap">
  {
      "imports": {
          "angularMFE": "http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.js"
      }
  }

</script>

System.import('angularMFE').then(module => {
    const element = document.getElementById('angular-mfe');
    console.log(module.AppComponent) // undefined
    //module.AppComponent.attachTo(element); // Adjust this to initialize your Angular component properly
}).catch(err => console.error('Failed to load MFE:', err));

I am struggling to extract the AppComponent from the generated file. How can I get hold of the AppComponent? What am I missing?
